# Prove that if $\theta$ is an angle with $\cos(2\theta)$ irrational then $\cos \theta$ is also irrational

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Prove that if $\theta$ is an angle with $\cos(2\theta)$ irrational then $\cos \theta$ is also irrational. (hint: recall that $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1$ )

Comment: So, did you use the hint to provide a proof...?

Answer (score 4):

**Further Hint:** Try proving the contrapositive:

> If $\cos \theta$ is rational, then $\cos 2\theta$ is also rational.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is some rational number, what can you say about $2x^2 - 1$?

Using this reasoning, suppose $\cos \theta$ *were* rational (even though it isn't).  Then what would you know about $\cos 2\theta$?  Why would this be a problem?

Conclude that since $\cos \theta$ being rational results in a problem, $\cos \theta$ must be irrational.

Comment: I'm still confused about this..can u provide me more information or write down this proof for me? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Milica I'm sorry, but I am not going to write down a proof for you.  You need to try and work out the problem yourself.  I've spelled out the steps here; if you don't understand a particular step or steps just let me know what you're confused about and I'll try to help.

Comment: Fair enough. does it help me somehow that cos2θ is an odd numeber?

Answer (score 2):

To add to what people have done here so far, here is a proof that if $x$ is rational, then $x^2$ is rational:

> Suppose that $x$ is rational.  Then $x=\frac ab$ for integers $a,b$, with $b\neq 0$.  $a^2$ is an integer, and $b^2$ is a non-zero integer.  Thus, $\frac{a^2}{b^2}=x^2$ is rational.

Now, given that $x=\cos\theta$ is rational, how could you show that $2x^2-1$ is rational?

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you so much!